# generic fill of some property in .net

Tags: .net

I have 3 lists of co, sto, and per.
Each entity co sto and per has a field GUID.
I need to make some method to generate guid for every list
something like

```
 public static void FillGuids (List<> list)
        {
            foreach ( var c in list)
            {

            }
        }
```

please help.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a generic approach and reflection:

```
public static void FillGuids<T>(List<T> list)
{
    PropertyInfo prop = typeof(T).GetProperty("GUID");
    if (prop == null) return; // no GUID property

    list.ForEach(x => prop.SetValue(x, Guid.NewGuid()));
}
```

If `GUID` is not a public property but a private field you can use `GetField()` instead:

```
FieldInfo field = typeof(T).GetField("GUID", BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Comment: thank you, but do you have any idea about using polymorphism to solve this?

Comment: @Ovidiu with polymorphism you need three methods for parameter types `List<co>`, `List<sto>` and `List<per>`, but would not need reflection but could simply set `x.GUID = Guid.NewGuid ()` since these three types have this field/property.

Comment: the point is I need to make that method with the parameter list<object> in order to have one single mehod

Comment: @Ovidiu but classes are invariant. if you make a method with`List<object>` as parameter you will not be able to pass a `List<co>` as argument, because those are completely different types. I suggest the generic approach as in my answer.